# Understanding conf file in /etc/modprobe.d/

Tags: drivers, kernel, nouveau

I am trying to understand how to use conf file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`. For instance on my system I define:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau.conf 
# debug nouveau
options nouveau debug="PGRAPH=debug"
```

After a shutdown followed by a fresh start here is what I see:

```
$ dmesg | grep nouveau
[    1.495465] [drm:nouveau_drm_init [nouveau]] Loading Nouveau with parameters:
[    1.495490] [drm:nouveau_drm_init [nouveau]] ... tv_disable   : 0
[    1.495515] [drm:nouveau_drm_init [nouveau]] ... ignorelid    : 0
[    1.495539] [drm:nouveau_drm_init [nouveau]] ... duallink     : 1
[    1.495563] [drm:nouveau_drm_init [nouveau]] ... nofbaccel    : 0
[    1.495587] [drm:nouveau_drm_init [nouveau]] ... config       : (null)
[    1.495611] [drm:nouveau_drm_init [nouveau]] ... debug        : PFIFO=debug
```

Which is confirmed by:

```
$ sudo  cat /sys/module/nouveau/parameters/debug 
PFIFO=debug
```

So it looks like upon startup the `nouveau` module is reading from another location the debug option (since `PGRAPH` != `PFIFO`). Where is this alternate file stored ? How do I find out which one is used ?

Comment: Try to run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot. It that doesn't help it is better to set the parameter in grub.

Comment: I wanted to check if it solves the problem. So I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nouveau` is starting from `initramfs`.

To change load options for this kind of modules you need to run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

to get the setting applied.